# Unable to export the .archive file to .ipa

Tags: ios, ipa

I have integrated **LazyPDFKit** into my application and am trying to generate the build, It is saying as below. Iam unable to export archived file into .ipa file. Below is the issue when I export it.

**Info.plist of “LazyPDFKitDemo.app/Frameworks/LazyPDFKit.framework” specifies a simulator platform for the CFBundleSupportedPlatforms key**[image]

Please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

**CFBundleSupportedPlatforms = { "iPhoneSimulator" },**

Replace with iPhoneSimulator to iPhoneOS

**CFBundleSupportedPlatforms = { "iPhoneOS" },**

Answer (score 0):

Check the CFBundleSupportedPlatforms key in you plist. Set the value to CFBundleSupportedPlatforms = {
                "iPhoneOS"
            }

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue perplex me a long time, and I finally find the way solved it, see my question:[framework specifies a simulator platform for the CFBundleSupportedPlatforms key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41099723/reactiveobjc-framework-specifies-a-simulator-platform-for-the-cfbundlesupportedp/41112807#41112807)

The solution is when export the `.ipa` file, uncheck the `bitcode`:

[image: uncheck bitcode]

I think the reason is `LazyPDFKit` do not support `bitcode`.