# ReactiveObjC.framework specifies a simulator platform for the CFBundleSupportedPlatforms key

Tags: ios

I replace the `ReactiveCocoa` to `ReactiveObjC` in `cocoapods`, because the `ReactiveCocoa` is `swift` only now, I have to do this.

But when I `archive` my `Ad hoc` `ipa`, there comes an issue:

```
ReactiveObjC.framework specifies a simulator platform for the CFBundleSupportedPlatforms key
```

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

**ATTEMPT - 1**
The teaching：https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62261
I try to edit the `Info.plist`, but not work for me:

```
<key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
<array>
<string>iPhoneOS</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After many attempts, solve this finally.

When export the `.ipa`, uncheck the `Rebuild from bitcode` option, then success.

[image: uncheck the Rebuild from bitcode]

I think `ReactiveObjC` do not support bitcode now, maybe in the future, there will not have this issue.