# Alamofire.framework” specifies a simulator platform for the CFBundleSupportedPlatforms key?

Tags: alamofire

Alamofire.framework” specifies a simulator platform for the CFBundleSupportedPlatforms key

Comment: when i am creating ipa for app then it is showing on after archieving the app .

Comment: possible solution...
http://stackoverflow.com/a/41112807/922681